# Count Numbers having $GCD$ equal to $X$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Given two integers $n,x$. Consider the interval $[l,r]$ with $l,r\in\mathbb Z$. I need to count the amount of numbers $y$ such that $l\leq y\leq r$ and $\gcd(n,y)=x$.

For example if $n=10 ,x = 2$ and the interval is $[1,10]$, then answer here is $4$ as from $1$ to $10$, there are $4$ numbers $2, 4, 6$ and $8$ such that their gcd with $10$ is $2$.

So, is there a good and efficient method to find this amount?

Answer (score 0):

An approach to problems involving gcd, is to use [Mobius Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

The number that you are counting can be expressed as a finite sum:
$$
\sum_{\substack{{l\leq y\leq r}\\{x|y}\\{\left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{n}{x}\right)=1}}} 1.
$$

By change of variable $xk=y$, the sum is:
$$
\sum_{\substack{{\frac{l}{x}\leq k\leq \frac{r}{x}}\\{\left(k,\frac{n}{x}\right)=1}}}1.$$

The condition $(a,b)=1$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{d|a, d|b} \mu(d)$. Thus the sum above is:
$$\sum_{\frac{l}{x}\leq k \leq \frac r x}\sum_{\substack{{d|k}\\{d|\frac{n}{x}}}}\mu(d).$$

After changing the order of summation, we have:
$$\sum_{\substack{{d\leq \frac r x}\\{d|\frac{n}{x}}}}\mu(d)\sum_{\substack{{\frac{l}{x}\leq k\leq \frac r x}\\{k\equiv 0 \textrm{ mod }d}}}1.$$

If you want an asymptotic formula when $r$ is large enough, we write the inner sum as:
$$
\frac{\frac r x-\frac{l}{x}}{d} + O(1).
$$

Then we arrive at the asymptotic formula for large enough $r$ (say $r\geq n$): 
$$
\left(\frac r x -\frac{l}{x}\right)\sum_{d|\frac{n}{x}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d} + O(\sigma_0(\frac{n}{x})),$$
where $\sigma_0$ is [the number of divisor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html).

The sum $\sum_{d|\frac{n}{x}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}$ has another expression:
$$\prod_{\substack{{p|\frac{n}{x}}\\{p \textrm{ prime}}}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)= \frac{\phi(\frac{n}{x})}{\frac{n}{x}}, $$
where $\phi$ is the [Euler Totient Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).